# list.remove function removes all items from mother-list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am running this code:

```
for i,bar in enumerate(bars[0]):
    if i!=len(options[0][0]):
        bar.remove('H')
```

this is the bars super-list:

```
[[['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V']], [['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V']], [['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V']], [['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V']], [['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V']], [['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V']], [['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V'], ['H', 'V']]]
```

As you can see, this is a 3-level list (a list of 7 lists of 7 lists of 2 strings).
I want to remove all the 'H's in the first 2nd-level list that comply with my if statement, though the first iteration of the loop removes all the 'H's,
what's wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you've put multiple references to the same list in your data structure instead of making independent lists.

Comment: Did you create this with list multiplication, by any chance? Give a [mcve].

Comment: Yes I created it with this 'for i in range (gridsize):'
        'bars.append(list([['H','V']]*gridsize))'

Comment: I've simplified the code in the question, I need the lists to be stored together because sometimes I need to iterate over all the lists.